# How to add new field to admin customer form in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop

Good evening,

I want to add new field to admin customer form. There where I can display the customer preferences. Is there any hook ? Or I need to override a controller (which) ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Alter customer table to add new field
2. override classes/customer.php to add new definition and variable
3. override controllers/admin/admincustomercontroller.php
4. override auth or myaccount on front controller

Comment: I have problem with add new filed to controllers/admin/admincustomercontroller.php. Can You help with this ?

Comment: You have to modify renderForm() and add your new field.